# How to display a navigation drawer in front of CAB?

Tags: android, toolbar, cab, drawer

I have an activity with an app bar and a navigation drawer. The app bar implemented using the new Toolabr class from AppCompat v21 library and the navigation drawer is displayed in front of it. Also the activity contains a list view with items which can be selected, so contextual action bar (CAB) is shown. But when the navigation drawer opens, it is displayed under CAB. Is there any way to display the navigation drawer in front of CAB?